# Window.history.go() or .go(-1) isn't working

Tags: reactjs, window

I don't know what is wrong. I have tried window.history.back(), window.history.go(-1) and window.history.go(). I have even tried to remove window from them all. The page keeps refreshing and the back button isn't working either. What I want to achieve is ability to go back to previous page(s).

```
import React from "react"
import { Link, graphql, useStaticQuery} from 'gatsby'
//import './header.module.scss'

import headerStyles from  './header.module.scss'

const Header = () => {

  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
      query{
        site {
          siteMetadata {
              title
          }
        }
      } 
    `)
  
  const navOption = () => {
      if( (window.location.pathname === '/') || (window.location.pathname === '/about') || (window.location.pathname === '/blog') || (window.location.pathname === '/contact')){
          return (
            <ul className={headerStyles.navList}>
            <li>
              <Link className={headerStyles.navItem} activeClassName={headerStyles.activeNavItem} to="/"> 
                Home
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link className={headerStyles.navItem } activeClassName={headerStyles.activeNavItem} to="/about"> 
                  About
                </Link>
              </li>
            <li>
              <Link className={headerStyles.navItem } activeClassName={headerStyles.activeNavItem} to="/blog"> 
                Blog
              </Link></li>
            <li>
                  <Link className={headerStyles.navItem } activeClassName={headerStyles.activeNavItem} to="/contact"> 
                  Contact
                  </Link>
              </li>
          </ul>
          )
      } else {
         return (
           <ul>
             <li><button onClick={window.history.go()}>Back</button></li>
           </ul>
         )
      }
    
  }
  return (
    <header className={headerStyles.header}>
      <h1>
        <Link className={headerStyles.title} to="/">
            {data.site.siteMetadata.title}
        </Link>
      </h1>
        { navOption()}
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got a work around this issue with

```
import { Link, graphql, useStaticQuery, navigate} from 'gatsby'
```

and as simple as this

```
<button onClick={() => {navigate(-1)}}>Back</button>
```

Thanks to you all